# Contains+add function for set, hashing the item only once

Tags: python, hash, set, contains

I'm looking for a way to add a `value` to a `set` but I also need to know if the value was in the `set` before I added it. With the additional restriction that the `hash` of the value is only calculated once (if it wasn't contained before I added it).

It would be quite easy without the restriction:

```
def contains_add(aset, value):
    contains = value in aset
    if not contains:
        aset.add(value)
    return contains
```

But unfortunatly the `hash` method of the value is quite expensive and I can't (easily) change that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to create a temporary `set` containing the `value` and then using [`set.isdisjoint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.isdisjoint) and [`set.update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.update) - both don't require to recalculate the `hash`:

```
def set_contains_add(aset, value):
    anotherset = {value}
    containsnot = anotherset.isdisjoint(aset)
    if containsnot:
        aset.update(anotherset)
    return not containsnot
```

To verify that this only calculates the `hash` once:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    def __hash__(self):
        print('hashing')
        return hash(self._value)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._value == other._value

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}({})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self._value)

>>> myset = set()
>>> set_contains_add(myset, MyClass(1))
hashing
False
>>> set_contains_add(myset, MyClass(1))
hashing
True
```

However this approach is definetly slower than the function presented in the question **if** the `hash` function isn't expensive!

---

Another way (**not really recommended because it uses private functions**) is to use the Python-C-API (3.5+) of `dict` (if one assumes that a `dict` would be an acceptable alternative to a `set`). Here simulated with Cython:

```
%load_ext cython

%%cython

from cpython.object cimport PyObject, PyObject_Hash

cdef extern from "Python.h":
    PyObject* _PyDict_GetItem_KnownHash(object mp, object key, Py_hash_t hash)
    int _PyDict_SetItem_KnownHash(object mp, object key, object item, Py_hash_t hash) except -1
    int _PyDict_Contains(object mp, object key, Py_hash_t hash) except -1

def dict_contains_add(object mydict, object key):
    cdef Py_hash_t keyhash = PyObject_Hash(key)
    cdef bint contains = _PyDict_Contains(mydict, key, keyhash)
    if not contains:
        _PyDict_SetItem_KnownHash(mydict, key, 0, keyhash)
    return contains

>>> mydict = dict()
>>> dict_contains_add(mydict, MyClass(1))
hashing
False
>>> dict_contains_add(mydict, MyClass(1))
hashing
True
```

On the plus side `dict_contains_add` is really fast (faster than the function presented in the question) but as it (mis-)uses private functions only avaiable for python 3.5 and later it may not be a good alternative.

Comment: You could also write a wrapper class that caches the hash value of whatever it wraps.

Comment: @BrenBarn Good idea, I will try that. Thank you.